# RemoteDeviceConnectEventArgs not found?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, rapi

I'm trying to get the sample code for RAPI2 to compile: http://rapi2.codeplex.com/documentation but, amongst other errors, it can't seem to find 'RemoteDeviceConnectEventArgs' any ideas why this is? I've included the DLL it comes with and have included System.Devices (but I don't have a System.Devices.Interop anywhere and not sure if it's something hte library should provide or if I should include another assembly for that namespace).

Comment: I have not had to use `rapi`, so have you tried asking in their forum? http://rapi2.codeplex.com/discussions

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I solved it by downloading the latest version of RAPI2 here : http://rapi2.codeplex.com/downloads/get/347232

It seems the version I downloaded previously was not up-to-date for an unknow reason.